# Why is the string not added to the property via Model.addObject?

Tags: spring, exception

I created @ControllerAdvice to handle BindException:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class globalControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(BindException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleMyException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("myerror",e.getErrCode());
        model.addObject("message",e.getMessage());
        model.addObject("exception","bind exception");
        model.setViewName("error");

        return model;
    }
}
```

And created **error.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>


  <title>Getting Started: Handing Form Submission</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


  <style>
table td{
vertical-align:top;
border:solid 1px #888;
padding:10px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error Page</h1>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>Error</td>
    <td th:text="${myerror}"/>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Message</td>
    <td th:text="${message}"/>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Exception</td>
    <td th:text="${exception}"/>
  </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And when executing, when I make a mistake on purpose, the page appears normally,but the properties are not filled in .That is, a table is created, but the text `"${myerror}"` , `"${message}"` , `"${exception}"` are not filled in with `e.getErrCode()` , `e.getMessage()` ,
 `"bind exception"`. Can anyone tell me what the problem is? thanks

Comment: Is this actually being resolved by thymeleaf or a static page (I suspect the latter).

Comment: Does your advice run? Add a line in handleMyException to print to console or log, or use a break point to see if your code there runs at all.

Comment: @GonenI I Yes, I added a line and really does not go into this function.And why is that?

Comment: @M.Deinum It looks like you're right, but why is that?

Comment: This file should be in `src/main/resources/templates` if you placed in in `src/main/resources/static` it will be treated as the default error page and not rendered by Thymeleaf but just rendered as is.

Comment: @M.Deinum yea i know it is located in the template

Comment: Try renaming it to something else as `error.html` (and change you r javacode accordingly ofcourse).

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you very much ! Can you tell me if it is possible to get the error status from Exception e ? beacause except for e.GetMessage(), I don't see anything useful to extract

Comment: What do you mean with error status?

Comment: @M.Deinum well, bad request for example

Comment: An exception doesn't carry that information. It is just a java exception why should that relate to a HTTP status code? It will just be a 500 as it is a technical exception.

Comment: @M.Deinum okey, thaks you a lot for helping me :)